# IKVM.NET - Using DllExport in the ikvm.lang namespace?

Tags: c#, dllexport, ikvm

I'm having a look at the IKVM.NET which has DllExport which is supposed to allow the export of C function in managed code.

The website gives a Java example but im looking to use it in C#. 
http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=78d507c1-f1e2-4706-9f41-866a34d0a2c0

When I add a reference to the IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll into my project and have a look at the DllExport it is an interface.

In the above link the java shows it as an attribute to the method. Any idea how to use this in C#

Comment: You don't need that. https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

Comment: Ya I use that but the problem is it doesn't work for the .Net Compact Framework, IKVM seems to support CF.